# Open a tab with a URL when link clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to open a new tab in the same browser when the 'Terms and Conditions' link is clicked which should return the URL: `http://localH:30321/OrchardLocal/TermsAndConditions`

So Far I have:

```
<p>Accept the <a href="~/" target="_blank" onclick="newwin()"> <span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>
<script>
    function newwin() {
        window.open("~/TermsAndConditions");
    }
</script>
```

This actually opens 2 new tabs in the same browser.

```
http://localH:30321/OrchardLocal/Users/Account/~/TermsAndConditions
```

which throws a page cannot be found for obvious reasons
ad then the second tab shows the home page:

```
http://localH:30321/OrchardLocal/
```

Tried removing the href and one of the ~/...cant seem to get it...any help guys?
thanks

Comment: check my answer.. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function newwin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open("/TermsAndConditions", '_blank');
}
```

by the way you cant use directly  "~" in javascript..if you want to use server code like this

```
function newwin(e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.open('<%= ResolveUrl("~/TermsAndConditions") %>', '_blank');
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<p>Accept the <a href="javascript: void(0)" target="_blank" onclick="newwin()"> <span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>
```

JS

```
function newwin(e) {

    window.open('<%= ResolveUrl("~/TermsAndConditions") %>', '_blank');

    }
```

or

```
     function newwin(e) {

            window.open("/TermsAndConditions", '_blank');

        }
```

OR pure asp.net code

```
<p>Accept the <a runat="server" href="~/TermsAndConditions" target="_blank" > <span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>
```

you have to add runat="server" attribute

Comment: thank you for reply I have tried this exactly but get the error: Line: 155
Error: Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of undefined or null reference

Comment: <p>Accept the <a href="~/" target="_blank" onclick="newwin()"> <span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>

Comment: <script>
    function newwin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('<%= ResolveUrl("~/TermsAndConditions") %>', '_blank');
    }
</script>

Comment: again thanks for taking the time to reply. when i click the link it is telling me Error: 'newwin' is undefined, also when the new tab loads the url is :'javascript: void(0)'

Comment: edited again. try last one you dont need javascript for that :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all sorry for the wrong answer:
As you want to open the url in new tab of same browser Which is not possible.It all depends on the browser settings.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1902352.aspx

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

IF browser setting are default(tested for FF)

this will work [Open new tab in same browser window](http://jsfiddle.net/Azh56/)

```
function openinnewTab() {
    var win = window.open("~/TermsAndConditions", '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='JavaScript:newwin('<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/OrchardLocal/TermsAndConditions")%>');'  >
```

and

```
<script>
    function newwin(url) {
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you cant use ~ directly in javascript

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this exactly but now on screen the Accept the " onclick="newwin()">Terms and Conditions appears and the terms And conditions can no longer be clicked?

Comment: <p>Accept the <a href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/OrchardLocal/TermsAndConditions.aspx")%>" onclick="newwin()"><span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>

Comment: <script>
    function newwin() {
        window.open('<%= ResolveUrl("~/TermsAndConditions") %>', '_blank');
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

One tab is for your href and the other for your onclick. sajad-lfc gave the rigth answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code

```
<p>Accept the <a href="~/" target="_blank" onclick="newwin()"> <span class="big-red">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>
<script>
    $("span.big-red").on("click", function () {
        window.open('www.yourdomain.com', '_blank');
    });
</script>
```

This is working perfectly hopefully works for you.