# open a new html page link from an jquery autocomplete search box in same window using in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery auto-complete search box. when i click on auto suggested page from dropdown, selected page is opening in new window but i need it to be open in same window like normal html link.

Comment: pls provide the fiddle

Comment: <script>
 $(function() {
     var availableTags = [
                       {value: "Coming Soon", url:"comingsoon.html"},
                       
                       ];
                       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                         source: availableTags,
                           select:function(event, ui) {
                           window.open(ui.item.url);        
                       }
                       });
 })
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to open a new tab in same window:

```
function openinnewTab() {
    var win = window.open("yourlink", '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Note:It also depends on your browser settings

And also see the answer give by me [**Open a tab with a URL when link clicked**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758538/open-a-tab-with-a-url-when-link-clicked/20758652#20758652)